# how can i filter undefined from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to create a MySQL Query which filters the data from MySQL. But i am experiencing a problem. I have wrote a for loop in which I am counting the elements of the divisions with jQuery. I have found a problem in that thing too.

First here is my function.

```
function filterFunnel(filterid){
    let filterLists = $("#funnel-filters").children().filter(".filter");
    let query = `SELECT * FROM funnel WHERE `;
    let count = 0;
    for(i=0;i<Object.keys(filterLists).length; i++){
        let dom = filterLists[i];
        if(dom.value === "Select" || dom.value === ""){

        }else{
            if(count >= 1){
                query += ` AND ${dom.id} = ${dom.value}`;
            }else{
                query += `${dom.id} = ${dom.value} `
            }
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    console.log(query);
}
```

When I execute this command, I get an error dom is not defined and I have found where does this originate from. 
[image]

If you look at the second function I executed, it returns 2 undefined.

Now when i use console.log() inside the loop, it is working but not working when I am using it outside it.

[image]

I think an async function will fix this problem but I don't know how to make this. I believe the problem is originated by the dom variable only.

Comment: I suggest you rethink your approach. First of all, you're generating SQL *in the client*, so it's wide open for [SQL injection](https://bobby-tables.com/). Secondly, even if you *do* move this to the backend, you would still need to use parametarised queries.

Comment: Oh, btw this is for my own personal use to manage things on my local machine so I don't think there's a need to move it to the backend. But can you please tell me what will be the better approach to generate a filter query? Also thanks for telling me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by checking if the response is undefined and if it is, then it will return the query. Here's what I did.

```
function filterFunnel(filterid){
    let filterLists = $("#funnel-filters").children().filter(".filter");
    let query = `SELECT * FROM funnel WHERE `;
    let count = 0;
    for(i=0;i<Object.keys(filterLists).length; i++){
        let dom = filterLists[i];
        if(dom === undefined){
            return query;
        }else{
            if(dom.value === "Select" || dom.value === ""){

            }else{
                if(count >= 1){
                    query += ` AND ${dom.id} = ${dom.value}`;
                }else{
                    query += `${dom.id} = ${dom.value} `
                }
                count += 1;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```